# Android Error - Access denied unable to save cropped image

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I have an Ionic 5/Angular app that uses the Ionic Native Camera plugin to take pictures and crop the images. The functionality worked fine until I updated to Android 11 (using note 10 plus). After the update, the following error is thrown when cropping: unable to save cropped image - access denied.

TS code:

```
takePicture() {
    this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
    this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]);

    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      targetHeight: 1920,
      targetWidth: 1080,
      sourceType: 1, // CAMERA
      destinationType: 0, // DATA_URL
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true,
      allowEdit: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     // Persist image data
    });
  }
```

App works fine on other devices. Also checked that my app, Gallery app and Photo Editor app has storage and camera permissions. I can take the picture and the cropper opens - after tapping on Done the message "Access Denied" is displayed followed shortly after by "Unable to save cropped image".

[image: Open camera]

[image: Crop image]

[image: Click done - Access denied error]

[image: Crop error]

1. What could be causing the error?
2. How can I see what app is set as the default cropping app for the device?
3. How can I clear/reset the default cropping app?

Note: I tested this on another device running Android 11 which resulted in the same error.

Comment: `access denied.` Ok. But to what?

Comment: `updated to Android 11.4` Where did you see that four?

Comment: did you find a solution please?

Comment: I too am having this issue and looking for a good solution

Answer (score 2):

In my case, 'cropping image' caused this problem. So if you don't care about cropping, change '**allowEdit: true**' to '**allowEdit: false**'. Then the error will be removed. However, don't forget that you will not be able to crop a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the change from Android 11 for external storage.

- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#modify-delete-media
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#access-file-paths

You must use one approach for Android 11, follow link above and update your photo editor app.

Comment: So what's the actual solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to opt-out of scoped storage by updating your AndroidManifest.xml with the attribute *android:requestLegacyExternalStorage*:

```
<manifest ... >
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

source: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage

Comment: OP said that the target is Android 11 and that link states:
Caution: After you update your app to target Android 11 (API level 30), the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute when your app is running on Android 11 devices, so your app must be ready to support scoped storage and to migrate app data for users on those devices.

Comment: Actually he said that he was running on an Android 11 device, not that he targets API Level 30, which is different. I should have warn that this solution is for API level <= 29, however it is clearly stated in the provided link.

Answer (score -4):

My best bet is, if you can, downgrading.
It *Did* work last version, correct?

Comment: It did work, but downgrading does not resolve the actual issue and can't expect users to downgrade their OS to resolve a bug in a single app.